# uso foreach en una vista mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

> En el **ViewBag.Deducciones**: me trae las deducciones que seleccione anteriormente.
>
> En el **ViewBag.DeduccionesEmpleados**: me trae las deducciones que tiene seleccionado el empleado().

El problema es que por cada deducción me recorre todas las deducciones asignadas a los empleados, de que otra manera podría ordenar eso.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>@item.EmpId</td>
                    @*<td>@item.EmpNombre @item.EmpApellido</td>*@
                    <td><p style="white-space: nowrap;">@item.EmpNombre @item.EmpApellido</p></td> 
                    <td>@item.PueDescripcion</td>
                    @*<td>@item.sueldo</td>*@
                    <td> @String.Format("{0:C}", item.sueldo) </td>
                    <td>@item.Ihss</td>
                    <td>@item.rap</td>



                    @*Deducciones Empleado*@
                    @if (ViewBag.DeduccionesEmpleados != null)
                    {

                        foreach (var Deduccion in (List<string>)ViewBag.Deducciones)
                        {
                            foreach (var Deduccionees in (IEnumerable<RecursosHumanos.Models.Con_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado>)ViewBag.DeduccionesEmpleados)
                            {

                                if (Deduccionees.EmpId == item.EmpId)
                                {
                                    if (Deduccionees.DedDescripcion == Deduccion)
                                    {
                                        <th>@Deduccionees.DetDedEmpValor</th>

                                        break;


                                    }

                                    else
                                    {
                                        <th> </th>
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Depende de que quieras lograr, pues ya que al menos como tienes ahora tu logica tienes dos conjuntos A y B y por cada elemento de A estas recorriendo todo en B ¿Que es lo que requieres?

Comment: que no vuelva a mostrar lo que ya uso del ViewBag.DeduccionesEmpleados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que antes de devolver dos viewbag, hagas un viewbag donde quites las coincidencias, así no tienes que hacer doble foreach en la vista.